# Keyboard glitches for some time when Ctrl key is pressed

Tags: windows-8, keyboard

I'm having some problems with my keyboard, if I press the Ctrl key it glitches for some time.

For example, if I press Ctrl and press Tab while it's still glitched the computer shuts down as if I pressed the Power On/Off button.
If I press a it "presses" Alt, A and a symbol I can't remember, if I recall correctly it's a currency symbol.
If I press Ctrl again it "presses" the ' key.

I'm using Windows 8 Single Language 64 bits with a ABNT2 keyboard.
The processor is a Intel Celeron G530 with 2GB of RAM.

Comment: Spilled anything recently?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using aerosol of compressed air to clean the keyboard to dislodge dirt and dust that can short the key circuits.  In the case of stubborn or sticky material lurking in the keyboard, you may need to carefully remove keys from the keyboard first to carefully clean.

More details here: [keyboard cleaning](http://www.howtogeek.com/65073/)

Comment: I had to buy a new one, but thanks anyway, since this could be useful in the future.